# wordpress - translating woocommerece menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, hebrew

I am using the woocommerece plugin and I uploaded the hebrew translation. Everything work well and the extra translation I needed I did with the loco plug in. There is 1 word that stayed in english in the my account menu "addresses" and i don't know why it stayed there and canwt find it in the pot file to translate it. Does anyone has some idea for it?

Comment: It looks like there are quite a few strings in the language pack are [not translated](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/he/default?filters%5Bterm%5D&filters%5Buser_login%5D&filters%5Bstatus%5D=untranslated&sort%5Bby%5D=original&sort%5Bhow%5D=asc&sorts=Sort&page=5) into Hebrew. You may want to consider contributing your language skills and adding some translations.

Comment: I dont know how to do it globaly, but localy I did it on the website I work on. Still the problem stayed. I think it may be a theme thing.

Comment: You can confirm that by switching to a default theme. Here's the [translator handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/glotpress-translate-wordpress-org/) and here's the homepage for the [Hebrew translation of WooCommerce](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/he/default/wp-plugins/woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a code snippest I found in http://www.remicorson.com/.
The snippest show you how to translate a single word, I used it with the problematic word, and it worked!

```
// Translating single words
add_filter('gettext',  'translate_text');
add_filter('ngettext',  'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) {
     $translated = str_ireplace('ADDRESSES',  'כתובות',  $translated);
     return $translated;
}
```